# fabric js code not working with newest version

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Hello I found this JS fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/efmbrm4v/2/) and i really need something like this to work. In the fiddle an older version of fabric js is used (1.4.0) and I cannot get it working in the newer versions (4.4.0). With the new version the uploaded image doesnt stay in the created clippingRect but it is visible on the whole canvas and i need it to stay visible only in the clippingRect object. Does anyone know what should i change in the code to make it work on the newest version ? Thanks in advance.

This is the code from the fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

var clippingRect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#DDD',
    opacity: 1,
    selectable: false
});
canvas.add(clippingRect);

function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {

            var instanceWidth, instanceHeight;

            instanceWidth = img.width;
            instanceHeight = img.height;

            var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
                width: instanceWidth,
                height: instanceHeight,
                top: (canvas.getHeight() / 2 - instanceHeight / 2),
                left: (canvas.getWidth() / 2 - instanceWidth / 2),
                originX: 'left',
                originY: 'top'
            });
            canvas.add(imgInstance);
            imgInstance.clipTo = function(ctx) {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                
                clippingRect.render(ctx);
                
                ctx.restore();
            };
            canvas.renderAll();
        };
        img.src = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
<br />
<label>Choose a File:</label>
<br/>
<br />
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you've linked to uses Fabric's old `clipTo` method which has since been replaced by the much easier and more powerful `clipPath` system.

Below is a 4-part tutorial series on how to clip objects using clipPaths.

- http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part1
- http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part2
- http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part3
- http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part4

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response I was able to do what I needed with clip path. But I ran into an issue. As seen in this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/pf15jbny/) The image loaded in the clip appears transparent to the background image. I found a question about this but there wasn't a clear answer at least i didn't know what to do with it. @melchiar

Comment: Feel free to open a new question and I will try to help